# When does mongoose schema update its keys?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I originally had this mongoose schema:

```
const scriptsSchema = mongoose.Schema({   
   title: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
   updated: { 
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now(),
        require: true
    }
});

export default mongoose.models.Script || mongoose.model('Script', scriptsSchema)
```

That i updated to

```
const constructDate = () => {
    var today = new Date();
    return (today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate())
}

const scriptsSchema = mongoose.Schema({   
   title: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
   updated: { 
        type: Date, 
        default: constructDate(),
        require: true
    }
});

export default mongoose.models.Script || mongoose.model('Script', scriptsSchema)
```

Since I wanted to have only the date (no time) as a default value in the 'updated' field. Problem is, the change does not reflect and whenever I create a new script document, the default 'updated' value is still `Date.now()`.
I tried dropping the collection, resetting the database... but somehow it doesen't notice the changes I've made in the schema.
My problem is not about updating the existing documents, since I am still in developement phase and I don't mind dropping all documents in the database. I just want the schema to update to its new version.

Comment: It might be picking the modal from the first part of the `||` operator

Comment: Yes I guess it might be, because `mongoose.models.Script` already exists. But in this case do you know the propper way to delete `mongoose.models.Script` so it takes the second option?

Comment: your can remove `mongoose.models.Script` from your exports, it will automatically take the your model